# Android Studio designer preview differs from what is seen on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout in Android Studio, that renders correctly in the preview of Android Studio, but on actual phones, it differs.
Preview: [Android Studio preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTtGR.png)
Phone screen: [Actually seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EyJc.png)
I use a <ViewStub> that is contained within a FrameLayout, and it is inflated with different contents at run time, in this example with a button. The rename field is `GONE` by default, and is made visible when the `rename` chip is pressed. The `done` button is also on the top of the card.

The XML is:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name">

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/card_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:text="delete"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipIconVisible="false"
            app:closeIconVisible="false" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/rename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:text="rename"
            app:checkedIconVisible="false"
            app:chipIconVisible="false"
            app:closeIconVisible="false" />

    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter new name..."
        android:inputType="text"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/done"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chipGroup"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="done"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/newname"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/newname"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is think the issue is that your frame layout has `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. This is likely to cause issues. Try setting the height to a fixed value or wrap content, depending on the views you're adding into the Stub.

If I was implementing this I'd probably use a vertical `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` and have a second `LinearLayout` for the text field and button. I find that overuse of `ConstraintLayout` often leads to weird layout issues.

Comment: ConstraintLayout was designed to avoid nested layouts. I've found that I'm almost always able to create what I want using only constraints, guidelines,and chains.

Comment: Maybe I've just not been fortunate with it, but I've found that whilst I can create what I want initially, constraint layout is often much less forgiving on different devices and screen sizes, and it's harder to understand for anyone trying to change it later.